# node js async/await request in function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Hi I've some trouble with async/await in nodejs. I would use this into my factory in this way

```
//foo.js    

   var rp = require('request-promise');

   function Foo(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    function create() {
        return new Foo(login());
    }

    async function login() {
        const options = {
            method: `POST`
            ,json: true
            ,uri: `http://xxxxxx/login`
            ,body: {username: 'abcd', password: '1234'}
        };
        try {
            const response = await rp(options);
            return Promise.resolve(response)
        }
        catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
  module.export.create = create;
```

So I call create into my test and I'm expecting that return will be execute after login, but flow isn't this!!!

```
var Foo = require('foo');

describe('using my utils into project', function () {

        it('using real case', function (done) {

            var foo = Foo.create();
            console.log(foo.options);
            done();
        });

    });
```

Test return me OK but in console I see `Promise { <pending> }` not real response after login process.
Where is my error? Is correct working in this way?

Comment: As always, it is not possible to convert async code into synchronous. Not even with async/await. The async keyword returns a promise, not a value. This is because the code is asynchronous and cannot return the value the moment the function is called. I strongly advise to learn promises first before using async/await

Comment: Ok, but can I use correctly async/await? This is my trouble

Comment: @slebetman await takes a promise and it waits for it's value to be available, and then returns that value. Is correct this?

Comment: `await` pauses an `async` function until a promise is resolved and the result of that promise is returned as a value. That is correct. However, `async` returns a promise. You cannot use `await` outside of an `async` function for the very reason that you cannot convert async code into synchronous code. The correct way is to design your `create` function to return a promise. Take a look at how the jQuery API is designed. Model your `create` function on how `jQuery.ready()` work.

Comment: @slebetman Ok this is clear, as you can see I'm using async/await in correct way and I've just edited my code to return a resolved promise but result is the same :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//foo.js    

var rp = require('request-promise');

function Foo(options) {
    this.options = options;
}

async function create() {
    var temp = await login()
    return Promise.resolve(new Foo(temp));
}

function login() {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            method: `POST`
            ,json: true
            ,uri: `http://xxxxxx/login`
            ,body: {username: 'abcd', password: '1234'}
        };
        try {
            const response = await rp(options);
            return resolve(response)
        }
        catch (error) {
            return reject(error);
        }
    });
}
module.export.create = create;
```

AND

```
async function main() {
    var foo = await Foo.create();
    console.log(foo.options);
}

main();
```